# How to set Image of dynamic PictureBox in onclick evetn

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to set the image of a picture box I created dynamically, I'm setting the image based on the tag of the parent control, but the image is not displaying

What I've tried so far

```
private void FinishTask_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string pnlTag = ((PictureBox)sender).Parent.Tag.ToString();
            PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
            pb.Tag = pnlTag;
            
            foreach (Control c in flpParent.Controls)
            {
                if (c.Tag == pb.Tag)
                {                       
                    pb.Image = Properties.Resources.complete;
                }
            }               
        }
```

Comment: This a quite convoluted method to assign a Bitmap (which you should not get from the Resources like that). Your `pb` object is never added to any container.

Comment: One of the reasons that the image is not displaying is that you throw away `pb`  at the end of this procedure. You are not showing `pb` in your form, and thus `pb.Image` is not shown. Is there a typing error in your code?

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse No not at all, The picture box is being creating dynamically so I'm trying to reference a picturebox with a specific tag but it's not showing

Comment: Jut as I said: at the end of the procedure you de PictureBox is thrown away. If you want to display it in a Control, you should add it to this Control, for instance to a Form, or to a UserControl, a GroupBox, or whatever ContainerControl